# 403 Forbidden -You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I know that the question was asked thousand times. 
I'm trying to install Wordpress. My folder is in /www/html/wordpress. I have downlowded the project manually from wordpress site. 
In wp-in config.php my configuration is fine (I have other project with the same configuration, just db name is different).
I set all the permissions to 755.
I have configured the sites-avaiable (the virtualHost works when I test with some random index.html).
Can someone tell me what else I can check ?

Answer (score 1):

Are all directories and files owned by www-data? The web server can only access them if he owns them. If not just do a

```
 $> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress/
```

Comment: I'm agree that, for regular setup, `www-data` must own the content of the WP's DocumentRoot, but *The web server can only access them if **it** own them.* is not correct statement :)

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: In my log file I have : hpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir